# SIOCGIFCONF return only loopback interface

Tags: linux, ioctl, network-interface

I want to get all network interfaces names present on the system. For system portability (Android included) I decided to write a method that performs this task using `ioctl` because I think (probably wrongly) that `ioctl` is one of the best for this task. So I wrote this code

```
struct ifconf contr_req;
contr_req.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_req = NULL;
if(ioctl(sock,SIOCGIFCONF,&contr_req) < 0)
    return NULL;


contr_req.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf = malloc(contr_req.ifc_len);
register int len = contr_req.ifc_len/sizeof(struct ifreq);
char **names = malloc(sizeof(char*)*len);

if(ioctl(sock,SIOCGIFCONF,&contr_req) < 0)
    return NULL;

struct ifreq *ini;
for(int i = 0;i < len; i++){
    ini = contr_req.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_req +
                sizeof(struct ifreq)*i;

    register name_len = strlen(ini->ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name)+1;
    names[i] = malloc(name_len);
    memset(names[i],0,name_len);
    memcpy(names[i],ini->ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name,name_len-1);
}

return names;
```

But the problem is, that it returns only the loopback interface. Can anyone explain where is the mistake or if there is another `ioctl` entry to return all interfaces names on the system?

(I don't want to use `getifaddr` or `if_nameindex` but `ioctl`.)

Comment: One advise: Don't use `register`. The compiler is much better at allocating registers and that keyword has since become obsolete. Also, it shouldn't be in example code, unless it is actually required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i discovered that SIOCGIFCONF returns only the interfaces that are connected.

Answer (score 0):

The ioctl call retruns all the interfaces, but you can't see them, because you are starting to check the results from the wrong point. You need to iterate the buffer that you previously allocated *contr_req.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf*

So change this:

```
ini = contr_req.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_req +
            sizeof(struct ifreq)*i;
```

to this:

```
 ini = (struct ifreq *)((char *)contr_req.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf +
            sizeof(struct ifreq)*i);
```

Comment: It does not return all interfaces because contr_req.ifc_len/sizeof(struct ifreq) is 1